# Language regularity implications

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I have to decide whether this implications are true or false and prove it.
Will you help me?

$L.\{a,b\}^{*}$ is regular $\implies$ $L$ is regular

$L.\{a,b\}^{*}$ is not regular $\implies$ $L$ is not regular

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For the first, consider any irregular $L\subset \{a,b\}^*$ with $\epsilon\in L$. What do you conclude?

For the second, what can you say about $L.\{a,b\}^*$ if $L$ is regular?

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                          a) Any language on alfabet {a,b} concated to {a,b}* must be regular because L.{a,b}* = {a,b}*                                             b) There is no language which is not regular when concated to {a,b}*, so the first term is always false so implication is always true. Am'I right?

Comment: @Milwoukee: What you say for (a) is not true; it **is** true for languages that contain $\epsilon$, which may be what you meant, but if $\epsilon\notin L$, then $L\cdot\{a,b\}^*\ne\{a,b\}^*$. What you say for (b) is again not true as you said it; what is true (and what I suspect you meant) is that if $L$ is regular, then $L\cdot\{a,b\}^*$ is regular, which does indeed mean that the implication in the problem is true.